# Typescript adding property to inline interface

Tags: typescript

i Would like to know if there is a way to add parameters to a interface of an already created object... Let me explain

I have a Product Class with these properties product.id product.name, now i want to add a quantity property to it...
I´m making an sql query that will give me the product object and the quantity and I want to add it to the product interface only to this const so I can do something like `console.log(products[0].quantity)`

I was tring to do something like this but obviously doesn't work

```
const products:Array<{...Product, quantity: number}> = (some sql query code with joins xd)
```

I found a way and is declaring all from scracth but I want to know if there is a better way to do this because this is a little cumbersome specially if the object has more properties

```
const products:Array<{id: number, name: string, quantity:number}>
```

Edit: Just found a way but I'm still all ears

```
const products:Array<Product & {quantity: number}>
```

Comment: Assuming you can’t modify the original Product type, your method of intersection types is usually what I’d defer to. You could also make a type alias for it if you need it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

## [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)

I'm assuming you already have a `Product` interface
i.e.

```js
interface Product {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}
```

You would do it like so

```js
const products = Array<Product & { quantity: number }> = await db.getFromDBExample();

// Example response
console.log(products); // { foo: 'hello', bar: 2, quantity: 3 }
```